# Prove that the core of this game is empty

Tags: game-theory, economics

A game (N, v) is simple if for every coalition S is a proper subset of N, either v(S) = 0 or v(S) = 1, In a simple game, a player, i, is said to be a veto player, if v(N \ {i}) = 0.

Suppose (N,v) is a simple game with v(N) = 1, and suppose there are no veto players in (N,v). Prove that the core of this game is empty.

Can someone show me how to do this question?

Comment: Hi -- welcome to math.SE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020)'s a reference and tutorial for typesetting math on this site.

Answer (score 1):

We have $v\left(N\setminus\{i\}\right)=1$ for all $i\in N$, and thus

$$
\sum_{i\in N}v\left(N\setminus\{i\}\right)=|N|
$$

but

$$
\sum_{i\in N}\sum_{j\in N\setminus\{i\}}x_j=(|N|-1)\sum_{j\in N}x_j=|N|-1
$$

for any allocation $x$, contradicting coalitional rationality.